# Finiteness of support of a module as $S$- and $R$- module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

$\DeclareMathOperator\nn{\mathfrak{n}}\DeclareMathOperator\mm{\mathfrak{m}}\DeclareMathOperator\Supp{Supp}\newcommand\card[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$Let $f:R\to S$ be a homomorphism  of commutative Noetherian  rings with identity that makes
$S$ a finite $R$-module.
Let $M$ be a (not necessarily finite) $S$-module. So $M$ is also an $R$-module.

> If $\card{\Supp_S M}\lt \infty$, is $\card{\Supp_R M}\lt \infty$?
> If $\card{\Supp_R M}\lt \infty$, is $\card{\Supp_S\ M}\lt \infty$?

---

What if:

1- $f$ is epimorphism?

or

2- $f$ is a monomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\operatorname{Supp}_R M| \lt \infty \iff |\operatorname{Supp}_S M| \lt \infty$.

Combine the following:

1. If $Q \in \operatorname{Supp}_S M$ then $P=Q \cap R \in \operatorname{Supp}_R M$, because $M_Q$ is a localization of $M_P$ (as $S$-modules). (This statement doesn't require $f$ finite.)
2. If $P \in \operatorname{Supp}_R M$ then there is at least one $Q \in \operatorname{Supp}_S M$ which lies over $P$ (i.e. $Q \cap R = P$):  The support of a sum of modules is the union of their supports, so the statement reduces to $S$-modules generated by one element i.e. $M=S/I$. Then $P \in \operatorname{Supp}_R S/I \implies P \supset I \cap R \implies \exists Q \supset I$ such that $Q \cap R = P$ (by "lying over" for the finite ring injection $R/(I \cap R) \subset S/I)$, and such $Q \in \operatorname{Supp}_S S/I$.
3. For each $P \subset R$ the set of $Q \subset S$ lying over $P$ is finite, because the fiber $S_P/PS$ is an Artinian ring (finite over the field $R_P/P$).

Notes:

1. It is not required that rings $R, S$ are Noetherian.
2. A finite epimorphism of commutative rings is surjective, so $\operatorname{Supp}_R M = \operatorname{Supp}_S M$ in this case.

Comment: thank you David. lying over is by finiteness of $f$, am i right?

Comment: in the Note2 u said "A finite epimorphism of commutative rings is *surjective*". do u mean *isomorphism*?

Comment: @13571 1. Right: lying over applies to finite injective ring homomorphism and $R/(I \cap R) \subset S/I$ is finite because $f$ is finite.  (I write $I \cap R$ to mean $f^{-1}I$.)  2. A ring epimorphism may not be surjective e.g. localization; a finite ring epimporphism is surjective.(https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM)

Comment: i'm pretty confused. 1-by epimporphism i mean surjective ring homomorphism. 2-under what assumptions u proved this? did u assumed $f$ is injective/surjective? 3- to be continued...

Comment: u say: "$M_Q$ is a localization of $M_P$" but $P$ is not prime ideal of $S$. i also have problem with your reduction: $M$ is not f.g. can u please help in this cases?

Comment: @13571 1. I pointed out that a ring epimorphism is not the same as a surjective ring homomorphism.  2. I didn't assume $f$ injective/surjective.  3. $f(R-P)$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $S, M_P=(f(R-P))^{-1}M$ as $S-$module, and $f(R-P) \subset S-Q$ so $M_Q$ is a localization of $M_P$ as $S-$modules. 4. I didn't assume $M$ is f.g., I said $M$ is a sum of (maybe infinitely many) submodules generated by 1 element e.g. $M=\Sigma Sm : m \in M$.

Comment: many thanks for your time David.--- in the 3ed part : 1- why the fiber $S_P/PS$ is an Artinian ring? 2- how this help us ? I can see that for any $Q$ lying over $P$ we have $PS\subseteq Q$.

Comment: @13571 1. $S_P/PS$ is an Artinian ring because it's finite over a field (a finite dimensional vector space has DCC property on subspaces).  2. An Artinian ring has finitely many prime ideals and all of them are maximal.  The primes $Q \subset S$ lying over $P \subset R$ correspond to the primes of the fiber $S_P/PS$.

Comment: thnx. 1- $PS$ is not an ideal of $S_P$ and so i cant understand what is the meaning of $SP/P_S$ ? 2- for any Q lying over P we have PS⊆Q, right? then any Q lying over P must contain $PS$. but how to continue to see it corresponds to the primes of that fiber

Comment: @13571 The fiber over the prime $P \subset R$ is $S_P/(PS)_P$, sorry for the confusion.  The prime ideals of the fiber correspond to the primes of $S$ lying over $P$ i.e. $Q \subset S$ such that $f^{-1}Q=P$.

Comment: Thank you very much